# Creating website wireframes on GNU/Linux with a free/libre tool

Tags: linux, open-source, wireframing

I want to create [website wireframes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe).

Locally/offline, or on my own server.

#### Requirements

1. License:

   - The tool needs to be **FLOSS**
   - The included graphics need to be licensed under the same license, or under a different **free content** license (which doesn’t require attribution when *publishing* wireframes)
2. OS:

   - Needs to be available for **GNU/Linux**
3. Features:

   - **Export** the wireframe as graphic (e.g., PNG)

#### Nice to have

- The exported wireframe should not include a watermark or something like that
- Included in a GNU/Linux distribution’s repository
- Availability for other OS (Unix-like, Microsoft Windows)
- Ability to import new graphic sets

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update**: The original tool seems to be no longer in development (last release from 2013-09). [@wb9688](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/16078/wb9688) mentioned that there’s a fork: https://github.com/prikhi/pencil

**Update 2**: [@nradk](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/39663/nradk) commented that the fork is no longer maintained. https://github.com/evolus/pencil is another fork, "in active development, and it is actually a rewrite of the old one".

---

[**Pencil**](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) ([License](http://pencil.evolus.vn/Licensing.html): GPLv2) is a "GUI prototyping tool" which is [available](http://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html) as

- a **stand-alone tool** for GNU/Linux (*), Microsoft Windows, and Mac OS X, and
- a **Firefox add-on** (**).

(*) It’s included in the software repositories of [Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pencil/) and [Fedora](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/pencil) (as `pencil`).

(**) The Firefox add-on [hosted by Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/pencil/) seems to be out of date (currently it’s version 1.0.6 from 2009), while the version [hosted on Pencil’s download page](http://pencil.evolus.vn/Downloads.html) seems to be the current one (currently version 2.0.5 from 2013).

---

I use Pencil as Firefox add-on. It opens a new window (with no Firefox chrome, it got its own menu bar etc). Sometimes, it gets kind of slow (e.g., when I rearrange graphics), but here my old PC might be to blame.

The graphics are called "Shape Collections" or "stencils". It ships with a few sets for different interfaces (including Web). Additional graphics can be imported. Here’s a sample wireframe I made to get an idea of some of the included graphics:

[image: Example webpage wireframe, using Pencil’s "Sketchy GUI" graphics]

Export of wireframes is possible as PNG, HTML, PDF, SVG, and ODT. A nice thing about the HTML ("Single web page") export is that you can add hyperlinks that link to other mock-ups (included in the same Pencil document), i.e., you can simulate user interactions.

Comment: Frankly I have the latest Pencil 2.0.5 on my Debian and it's quite buggy. I never managed to get the HTML export to work. It just generates empty documents or such with part of what I actually have in Pencil.

Comment: Also mention [this fork](https://github.com/prikhi/pencil)

Comment: That fork too is no longer maintained. There is another one [here](https://github.com/evolus/pencil) in active development, and it is actually a rewrite of the old one.

Answer (score 3):

While not primarily a wireframing tool, **Inkscape** tends to be used for wireframes and mockups in open-source circles--**[GNOME](https://gitlab.gnome.org/Community/Design/) and [elementary](https://github.com/elementary/mockups)** use it, for example. (Similarly, in the proprietary world, UX designers tend to use generic vector design tools like Sketch and Figma.)

If you're looking for components to start with, it'll depend on the platform you're designing for.

- For GNOME and elementary, I recommend starting with the svgs from their design repositories (links above).
- For web and mobile, you can find various open-source wireframe kits around the web. Inkscape can import AI files, but, unfortunately, [many](https://github.com/teracyhq/wireframe) [kits](https://github.com/elwinvdhazel/The-Wireframe-Kit) are Sketch-only. You may use the proprietary web app Figma to upload the Sketch file and then export it as an SVG for use in Inkscape.

---

**Update Sep. 23:**

There are two relatively new tools being developed as FOSS alternatives to Sketch/Figma (the current industry standards):

- **[Penpot](https://penpot.app/)**, which is a web application that can be self-hosted (and also offers a SaaS version).
- **[Akira](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.akiraux.akira/)**, a desktop Linux app that was designed for elementary OS, but can be installed on basically any Linux distro via [Flatpak](https://github.com/akiraux/Akira#flathub-beta)

Right now, both are in alpha. Penpot is farther along in terms of features and also has a bigger team behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://penpot.app/.

The website says "[penpot is a] browser-based design tool". I have used Penpot in the past, I'm not connected to it. It can be used online (free of charge), or you could install it on your own server.

Penpot offers many plugins, one of them for creating wireframe designs. Check out https://penpot.app/libraries-templates.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you may consider the [Mockplus](http://www.mockplus.com/) for a while. It can help you to create brilliant prototypes/wireframes both for mobile phones and webs.

- With it, you could export images (PNG & GIF)or htmls to your stakeholders to present your ideas and designs.
- For the app project, you could even preview it on your smart phone by scanning the QR code generated by the project.
- It supports both Windows and Mac.
- The interactive design in Mockplus is fully visualized, that's WYSIWYG. With a simple drag-and-drop to build interactive prototypes effortlessly.It has several trigger command such as rotating, resizing, etc. As well as a set of  pre-designed components, including pop-up panel, stack panel, scroll box, sliding drawer and image carousel, make you create fully interactions faster and easier.

[image]

Comment: This does not meet 2 of my 3 requirements, does it? It doesn’t seem to be free/libre software, and it doesn’t seem to be available for GNU/Linux.

Comment: While, it has a version for free, actually! http://www.mockplus.com/download

Comment: @Charles the OP wants Free as in speech, not free as in beer.  Although free is usually a result of Free.